# If $id:(X,d_1)\to (X,d_2)$ is continuous then what will be $X$?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, continuity

Let, $id:(X,d_1)\to (X,d_2)$ is continuous. Then which is(/are) TRUE ?

(A) $X$ must be singleton.

(B) $X$ can be any finite set.

(C) $X$ can NOT be infinite

(D) $X$ may be infinite but NOT uncountable.

**My Thought :**

If $X$ is singleton then the function is continuous trivially but the condition is not necessary. So (A) is FALSE. If $X$ is finite then $d_1$ and $d_2$ are equivalent and so the function is continuous. So, (B) is TRUE. If $X=\mathbb R$ and $d_1$ is discrete metric and $d_2$ is any metric then then the function is continuous. So (C) and (D) are FALSE.

Am I right or wrong ? If I am wrong then where my fallacy ?

Comment: With discrete metric on $X$, any function $X \to Y$ is continuous.

Comment: @SPanja, is it a CSIR question? Which year?

Comment: @  Jesse P Francis): No.It is not CSIR question...Probably NBHm question..But not sure..In this moment I am unable to remember from where I collect this question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right. It's a bit of a trick, since taking $d_1=d_2$ we see $X$ could be any metric space whatsoever.

Comment: But the answer is given  (A) and (D) are correct.. In option (D) $\mathbb R$ is infinite and uncountable..So  $X$ may be uncountable. I think  the given answer is wrong...

Comment: @S.Panja-1729: I agree; the given answer is wrong.

Comment: I agree as well.